# Precedence in cremation rites

Tags: death, cremation

For a woman with two married daughters (with no children) but no husband, who is in-charge of the cremation rite? [This site](http://ramaswamysastry.blogspot.com/p/understand-death-to-understand-life_84.html) says the precedence goes to the eldest daughter, but it is highly unusual for women to do that I believe. Is the precedence list given in the site correct?